# Mac software for examining a Time Capsule backup of a defunct computer

Tags: osx, backup

I have several Macs and have been using Macs for years. I have a `.sparsebundle` file copied from a defunct Time Capsule. The backup is of a defunct mac.

A long time ago, I used the at-the-time active Time Capsule to 'restore' all the files I thought I needed. Unfortunately, I now realize I'd put some files in a directory at root level (made a `/space` directory) and not all the files were in the `/Users` directory.

I'd like to examine the sparsebundle without actually 'restoring' a Mac from it (since it's years out of date). My current mac is on 10.8.5 (Mountain Lion) but I could update to Mavericks if needed. I don't actually remember the version the sparsebundle was made with but I'm guessing it could be as far back as Tiger (10.4). I'd be willing to pay a reasonable price (ie doesn't have to be freeware).

Is there a program for examining Time Capsule backup images?

Answer (score 3):

I used a tool called [BackupLoupe](http://www.soma-zone.com/BackupLoupe/) ([screenshots](http://www.soma-zone.com/BackupLoupe/a/ScreenShots.html)) to find out why my hourly backups took so long but you can read/index different Capsules and also restore files. The feature list is very long and the tool is totally usable. Here are some of the features you might honor:

- Open files directly without restoring them first
- Drag&Drop restore items to any location
- Handles multiple Time Machine disks
- Handles backups in non-standard locations

---

Concerning the price, it is *Trustware* and costs 5$

[image: Trustware]

Answer (score 0):

A sparse bundle can be mounted as an image by double-clicking it in Finder. On my machine, the resulting volume name is `Time Machine Backups`. Inside that volume, in the `Backups.backupdb` folder, you will find a folder with your defunct computer's name. Inside that you will find a folder for each backup, and a link called `Latest` for the last one made. You should be able to drag files from those folders and drop them wherever you please on your hard drive.